# Functors on Opposite Categories

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

I am curious about the following question:

> Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category and $\textbf{Set}$ be the category of
> sets. What is the difference between
> $\text{Funct}(\mathcal{C}^{\text{op}},\textbf{Set})$ and
> $\text{Funct}(\mathcal{C},\textbf{Set}^{\text{op}})$? What is the
> difference between
> $\text{Funct}(\mathcal{C}^{\text{op}},\textbf{Set}^{\text{op}})$ and
> $\text{Funct}(\mathcal{C},\textbf{Set})$? Here
> $\text{Funct}(\mathcal{C},\textbf{Set})$ is the category of functors
> from $\mathcal{Cc}$ to $\textbf{Set}$.

I cannot see any differences between them.

In fact, this is Exercise 1.3.v (p.22) of the book "Category Theory in Context" ([link to the book](http://www.math.jhu.edu/%7Eeriehl/context.pdf)). For the reason why I am interested in this exercise, while reading "Categories and Sheaves" by Kashiwara and Schapira, they say that for an object $A\in\mathcal{C}$ the functors $\text{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(-,A)$ and $\text{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(A,-)$ are in $\text{Funct}(\mathcal{C}^{\text{op}},\textbf{Set})$ and
$\text{Funct}(\mathcal{C}^{\text{op}},\textbf{Set}^{\text{op}})$, respectively. But I think writing $\text{Funct}(\mathcal{C}^{\text{op}},\textbf{Set}^{\text{op}})$ is notationally tedious, why don't we just write $\text{Funct}(\mathcal{C},\textbf{Set})$?

Comment: While a functor $F^\text{op} : \mathcal{C}^\text{op} \to \mathsf{Set}^\text{op}$ contains the same data as a functor $F : \mathcal{C} \to \mathsf{Set}$, we still _think_ about them differently. Much like a (finite dimensional) vector space is "the same" as its dual, but we think of them differently. This analogy isn't perfect because of the naturality issue, but it should provide at least some motivation for caring about two objects which have different names despite being formally the same.

Comment: The objects are “the same” but the morphisms are reversed. So the categories are not equivalent (unless the domain is empty).

Comment: @ZhenLin Are you saying that $\text{Funct}(\mathcal{C}^{\text{op}},\textbf{Set}^{\text{op}})=\text{Funct}(\mathcal{C},\textbf{Set})^{\text{op}}$?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Thank you! I got the point.